# How to feed complex number input to a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, complex-numbers

I am trying to train a neural network with complex numbers as input, as generally suggested I split the complex number into real and imaginary part for feeding the data into network. However, what if I use modulus (argument) and phase of the complex number instead of real and imaginary part? How will it affect my training process? I am unable to have a conclusive thought on this.